# Remove https:// from URL while still serving SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, https, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite the URL displayed in a browser to eliminate the `https://` portion. Not being familiar with Apache coding, I have tried many different ways of tweaking other code to achieve the result, but without success.

My `.htaccess` file includes 310 redirect rules, as well as some rewrite conditions, all of which are presently working:

```
# Force browswer to use SSL, even when referring URL is non-secure
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Catch-all for any potential 404 error (file not found) will 
# redirect to the index (/) page
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Any help on this front is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Remove https:// from URL while still serving SSL" you can't. http:// is served over plain http, not ssl.

Comment: Masking real URLs is a browser "feature" (and, in my opinion, a source of endless confusion). In 2017 all browser vendors seem to agree in showing the protocol for SSL. They can change their mind any time, but it's not something you can do anything about as webmaster.

Answer (score 2):

> I am attempting to rewrite the URL displayed in a browser to eliminate the `https://` portion.

I would be curious to see your "attempts". And why you are wanting to do this?

Basically, you can't.

You have no control over *how* the browser *displays* the protocol (ie. `https`, or `http`), or any part of the URL for that matter, in the browser's address bar. And any attempt to "rewrite" the URL to remove `https://` is only likely to stop your site serving content over SSL - which is not your intention. The only way to change the physical appearance of the URL in the browser's address bar is by changing the physical URL. This is basic browser security - the website should not be able to control this behaviour. You don't want the website to be able to pretend to be something it is not (ie. *phishing*).

However, some browsers do allow the *user* to control this behaviour to some extent. For example, Opera will show a more friendly URL by default, omitting the `HTTP` protocol and even the query string. However, this "friendly" display format can be disabled in settings to instead show the complete "real" URL.

Generally, by default, browsers tend to hide the protocol when serving over plain HTTP and show it only when serving over HTTPS - an additional indication to the user that the site is secure. Any attempt to remove the protocol is only going to disturb user trust.

Comment: What about with websites like twitter? They change the URL without actually refreshing the page.

Comment: @Adam No, they don't, nobody can do so. Please Google about iframes and AJAX.

Comment: @user82217: That's kind of what I was thinking. My attempts were to use the rewrite module to remove the protocol, but it led to problems (no surprise). I want to do this because most browsers have some visual indication (e.g. a lock) which tells the user that the site is secure, so having https:// (eight additional characters) in the URL is redundant. Just trying to emphasize my site/brand and eliminate unnecessary surplusage. I suppose I will have to wait until browsers decide to hide the protocol for secure sessions. Thanks!